# Babelify used with tsify and firebase does not generate correct code

Tags: typescript, firebase, babeljs, babelify

I have landed at this point after a long chain of changes to my build environment. I never used babel because it was not neccessary. But including the firebase package broke the build and all solutions I found online suggested using babel to transform the package to something that compiles. But when I am now compiling my code firebase can't be found at runtime.

My ts code:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';

const auth = firebase.auth();
```

which generates this error at runtime:

```
Login.ts:15 Uncaught TypeError: app_1.default.auth is not a function
```

My gulp script looks like this:

```
        let buildTask = browserify({
            basedir: Config.srcPath,
            debug: Flags.isDebug,
            entries: ['./index.ts'],
            cache: {},
            packageCache: {}
        })
            .plugin('tsify')
            .transform('babelify', {
                presets: [
                    ["@babel/preset-env", {
                        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
                        "corejs": 3,
                    }]
                ],
                sourceMaps: true,
                global: true,
                extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
                ignore: [/\/node_modules\/(?!(firebase\/|@firebase\/))/]
            })
            .bundle()
            .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
            .pipe(buffer());
```

And my tsconfig for completeness:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strict": true,
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "target": "es6"
    }
}
```

I am thankfull for any pointers!

Answer (score 0):

Wel it turns out it did, I just had to add two imports:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
```

I don't really understand what an import without something imported does in typescript. But it seems like it triggers that the js code is being imported by babel (or browserify?)